# Формирование массива по ключу

Tags: массивы, orm, php, kohana

В бд есть две таблицы: одна суперкатегории, вторая просто категории, естественно у них связь по `id`.

Что нужно... Нужно взять их из бд в массив (ассоц.) , для того чтобы вывести стандартно через foreach , т.е. тут вложенный `foreach` должен быть. Я использую Kohana 3.2, но мне кажется это не существенно, мне главное понять как происходит формирование и вывод такого дела.

Т.е. должно получится что-то вроде:

```
Supercategory 1
Category 1
Category 2
Category 3
Supercategory 2
Category 1
Category 2
Category 3
```

и т.д.

п.с. Фреймворк это для вариантов решения этой задачи на Query Builder или ORM я указал. А так просто пока сам принцип хочу понять.

Нда, сам вопрос по сути уже конечно же решен. Но у меня так и не получилось это нормально вывести, прийдется код выложить:

```
// берем суперкатегории по language_id
        $supercategories = DB::select()->from('supercategories')
            ->where('language_id','=',$this->language_id)
            ->execute()->as_array();

        $data = array();

        foreach ($supercategories as $supercategory) {

            $item['supercategory'] = $supercategory;

            // возьмем категорию по language_id и supercategory_id 
            $categories = DB::select()->from('categories')
                                      ->where('language_id','=',$this->language_id)
                                      ->where('supercategory_id','=',$supercategory["id"])
                                      ->execute()->as_array();
            // вывод суперкатегории                          
            echo "-".$supercategory["name"]."<br />";

            // получаем категорию                         
            foreach ($categories as $category) {

                $item['categories'][] = $category;

                // вывод категории
                echo "--".$category["name"]."<br />";

            }

            $data[] = $item;

        }
        //--------------------
        // вывод данных
        echo "<font color='red'>";

        foreach ($data as $s){

            // вывод суперкатегории
            echo "-".$s["supercategory"]["name"]."<br />";

            foreach ($s["categories"] as $category) {
                // вывод категории
                echo "--".$category["name"]."<br />";
            }
        }
        echo "</font>";
```

Что в итоге? В итоге вот что:

```
-Веб
--jQuery
--php
-Спорт
--Футбол

-Веб
--jQuery
--php
-Спорт
--jQuery
--php
--Футбол
```

Т.е. 1-ый раз срабатывает замечательно, тогда когда делаю выборку и сразу вывожу, а второй раз (красным) уже портятся данные, что может быть не так?

Comment: Пропущено ``$item['categories'] = array()``, поэтому категории постоянно дописываются

Comment: Да, дей-но я упустил 2-ой момент, а 1-ое это я специально для теста сделал.

Comment: В общем все заработало, еще раз спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сам принцип:

```
$array = array();

// получение массива суперкатегорий
foreach($supercategories as $supercategory)
{
    $item['supercategory'] = $supercategory;
    $item['categories'] = array();

    // получение массива категорий
    foreach($categories as $category)
    {
        $item['categories'][] = $category;
    }

    $array[] = $item;
}
```

Вывод:

```
foreach($array as $item)
{
    // вывод суперкатегории: $item['supercategory']

    foreach($item['categories'] as $category)
    {
        // вывод категории: $category
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, а массив такой как сформировать? Вот это самое главное.

Comment: @Viczech, обновил. Теперь там самое главное

Comment: Да, как раз то что надо. Спасибо!

Comment: а еще раз можно как это вывести? Только этот код не трогайте.

Comment: Эхх, спасибо, правда все-равно чудит мой скрипт, но не буду вас мучать.

Comment: @Viczech, видимо чудит что-то еще